# Can two elements on two different pages have the same ID in HTML/CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to have elements with the same ID on two different pages?

How do jQuery selectors work in such cases?

Comment: What kind of application is it? it can work if it's NOT a single page application

Comment: How is this question a duplicate of that one? This one is asking about elements with the same ID on two different pages entirely. Or were the duplicate votes cast based on a misconception that the unique ID restriction extends across multiple pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of the elements with the same ID resides on its own page, then jQuery will only ever see one element at a time, since only one such element with that ID exists in each page context at a time. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

An [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) needs to be unique on one page.

The intention of assigning an `id` to an element, as opposed to a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class), is to say:

> this element has a unique identity

If two elements on separate pages are representative of the same data, however, it is acceptable for them to have the same `id`, for example:

*page_1.html*

```
<div id="title">About Me</div>
```

*page_2.html*

```
<div id="title">My Projects</div>
```

Conversely, if the elements on two pages represent different data, and you assigned them the same `id`, whilst technically valid, it may make it difficult to understand your code at a later date, for example:

*page_1.html*

```
<div id="contact">My Name</div>
```

*page_2.html*

```
<div id="contact">click to contact</div>
```

---

As an example of a scenario where one might be tempted to use the same `id` for elements with different data, I share the following experience in case it helps anyone think though a similar situation...

I recently tried to be "clever" by assigning a dynamically injected element into a page with the same `id` (an `<input>` element in an editing content scenario), regardless of its location (programatically it was only ever present in the page once).

The pros of this approach were:

- A single CSS style definition
- A single HTML template for the dynamic element
- An anticipated similarity in subsequent event handling logic

However I found I always needed a way to identify the instance uniquely, and so I ended up using data attributes that indicated the unique instance.

It got pretty complicated pretty quickly and I kind of regretted my approach and still wonder if assigning a unique `id` would have made the program logic simpler (but I don't have time to refactor at the moment).